# Send data to a specific client by the client's Windows User Name with SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr, windows-authentication

I have a sort of desktop-like web app, with draggable items, and on every item drag-drop, the db updates with new serialized data. Now every time one user changes his layout, all his logged in computer should be updated live.

How would i go around sending the data only to users with this property:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

Basically it should look something like this:

```
this.Clients.WithWindowsName("windowsusername").sendData(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to send the windows name to the server. The quickest way  is sending it from the client as a header because it will be included in the `Start()` call thus you don´t need an additional `proxy.Invoke()`:

**Client side**

```
_connection = new HubConnection(_uri);
_connection.Headers.Add("windowsName", "John");
await _connection.Start();
```

**Server side**

That "windowsName" header will be your identity. To make sure SignalR recognizes that header as the identity, you need to create an implementation of `IUserIdProvider`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace YourServer
{
    public class UserIdProvider : IUserIdProvider
    {
        public string GetUserId(IRequest request)
        {
            return request.Headers.Get("windowsName");
        }
    }
}
```

And then plug it into the global dependency resolver:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var idProvider = new UserIdProvider();
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => idProvider);

        // TODO configure signalR here
    }
}
```

Whenever you access `User.Identity.Name` it will match the "windowsName", but you don´t even need it as explained bellow.

As you say, a user can login from several computers. The best way to handle this is creating SignalR groups:

```
public override Task OnConnected()
{
    var windowsName = Context.Headers.Get("windowsName");
    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, windowsName);

    return base.OnConnected();
}
```

This will create a SignalR group with the name of the Windows machine.
If the user logs-in with other machine, he´ll be added to the same group.
You don´t need to remove anything inside `OnDisconnected` as SignalR will take care of it for you.

Groups are very handy because whenever you send a message to a group, all connected machines will be notified:

```
Clients.Group("John").sendData(data);
Clients.Group(User.Identity.Name).sendData(data);
```

So it´s fine to create a group even for a single user (connecting from several machines).

Comment: This is extremely useful! Thank you so much for this amazing answer and a very understandable explanation! Good day to you!